# Finding heaviest path through triangle

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell

I am doing Project Euler problem 67 which involves finding the heaviest path through a triangle of integers like this one (this is a smaller version from an earlier problem)

```
75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23
```

This is my code:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM)

addRows :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
addRows xs@(x:_) (y:ys) = x + y : addMid xs ys ++ [last xs + last ys]
    where addMid (a:b:bs) (c:cs) = c + max a b : addMid (b:bs) cs
          addMid _         _     = []


parse :: (Integral a, Read a) => String -> [[a]]
parse = map ((read <$>) . words) . lines


main = do 
    tri <- liftM parse $ readFile "Triangles.txt" 
    return $ maximum . foldl1 addRows $ tri
```

The above code works, however it seems inefficient in some respects. It seems like I'm not being as lazy as I should be with regards to my concatenation and use of `last`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The last element...

> It seems like I'm not being as lazy as I should be with regards to my concatenation and use of last.

Yes. Let's have a look at an example and check `addRow`'s behaviour:

```
       6
     1   4
   3   5   2
 9   1   2   6
```

```
addRows [6] [1, 4] = (6 + 1) : addMid [6] [4] ++ [6 + 4]            (1)
                   = 7       : []             ++ [10]
                   = [7, 10]

addRows [7, 10] [3, 5, 2] = (7 + 3) : [5 + max 7 10] ++ [10 + 2]    (2)
                          = [10, 15, 12]
```

Let's check how often you actually use each number. In `(1)`, you use `6` twice, and both `1` and `4` once. In `(2)`, you use `7` twice, `10` twice, and all of the other numbers once. Hm. Does this hold for a fourth line?

```
addRows [10, 15, 12] [9, 1, 2, 6] 
     = (10 + 9) : addMid [10, 15, 12] [1, 2, 6] ++ [12 + 6]
     = (10 + 9) : 1 + (max 10 15) : 2 + (max 15 12) : [] ++ [12 + 6]
```

### Using a function that "does things right"

This pattern seems to hold. You always use the elements in the first list twice, and the once in the second list only, well, once. This sound like it should be possible to `zipWith` the first elements with themselves somehow. If we were able to pattern match on the last element, this would be

```
(x:xs:[y]) -> x : zipWith max (x:xs:[y]) (xs:[y]) ++ [y]
```

However, the dreaded `last` element makes this hard. We could write our own zip function:

```
transformLine :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
transformLine xs@(x:_) = x : go xs
  where
    go [y]           = y
    go (a: ys@(b:_)) = max a b : go ys
```

It's important that we only use `cons` to gain a maximum of laziness. This function will transform a line into another that's exactly one number longer:

```
transformLine [6]   == [6, 6]
transformLine [1,4] == [1, 4, 4]
```

It is therefore a list that can simply get summed onto the next line:

```
    [6,  6]   |->   [ 7, 10, 10]    | ->  [10, 15, 15, 12]
 +  [1,  4]   |   + [ 3,  5,  2]    |   + [ 9,  1,  2,  6]
 =  [7, 10] ->|   = [10, 15, 12] -> |   = [19, 16, 17, 18]
```

That way, `addRows` is simply

```
addRows xs ys = zipWith (+) (transformLine xs) ys
```

### Turn your world upside down

However, we can also turn the triangle upside down and start with the longer lines:

```
 9   1   2   6
   3   5   2
     1   4
       6
```

Which makes this a lot easier, because we're now *reducing* the information instead of gaining additional:

```
     / 9 1 2   (init first line)  \
 max                               \
     \ 1 2 6   (tail first line)    (+)
                                   /
       3 5 2   (second line       /
```

Or, in actual code:

```
addRows :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
addRows xs ys = zipWith (+) ys $ zipWith max xs (tail xs)
```

However, now it's necessary to `reverse` the triangle beforehand or flip the arguments of `addRows`:

```
head . foldr1 addRows . reverse $ tri

head . foldr1 (flip addRows) $ tri
```

Note that `head` is fine here, since `addRows` always decreases the number of elements in the accumulating list, therefore you end up with a singleton. Also note that `foldr` is usually lazier on lists.

## ... and the oddities

While the previous section was concerned with laziness and `last`, this one contains general remarks:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM)
```

This isn't necessary, since `IO` is also an instance of `Functor`. And since the [Applicative-Monad-Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) every `Monad` is also an `Applicative` and therefore a `Functor`.

```
parse = map ((read <$>) . words) . lines
```

The `<$>` here is quite hard to read, especially since there are two operators next to each other (`<$>` and `(.)`). A simple `fmap` is easier to the eye:

```
parse = map (fmap read . words) . lines
```

Alternatively use `map`, since you're working with lists.

```
main = 
    ...
    return $ maximum ...
```

`main` should have the type `IO ()`. If you want to print the number, use `print` instead of `return`.

## Summary

Other than the few oddities, well done. The `last` issue isn't that easy to solve unless you write another function or change your point of view. However, if you manage to actually reduce the amount of available information in your `fold*`, your usually on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! I know `main` is supposed to return `()` but I was using it in ghci so it printed the result anyway. 

Also couldn't `addRows xs ys = zipWith (+) ys $ zipWith max xs (tail xs)` be replaced with `addRows xs ys = zipWith3 (\x y z -> x + max y z) xs ys $ tail ys` or even `addRows = (tail <*>)  .  zipWith3 (\x y z -> x + max y z)` It then wouldn't require reversing I don't think.

Comment: I created an answer with some comments on avoiding the use of `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid overkill generality**

In the definition:

```
parse = map ((read <$>) . words) . lines
```

The operator `<$>` is obscure to many, but looking through [the examples of the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-), I saw this:

> ```
> >>> (*2) <$> [1,2,3]
> [2,4,6]
> ```

That looks strikingly similar to  `` (*2) `map` [1,2,3] ``

In fact substituting from `<$>` to `map` works the same!

```
parse = map (map read . words) . lines
```

I suggest my version with `map` as the same result is achieved using more basic and well known functionality.

Comment: Indeed `<$>` is just an infix version of `fmap` which is equivalent to `map` when operating on lists.

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment on @Zeta's answer...

I think you can avoid the `reverse` if you define things like this:

```
solve :: [[Int]] -> [Int]   -- row length increases
solve rows = foldr1 go rows
  where go xs ys =   -- note: xs is one smaller than ys
           zipWith max (zipWith (+) xs ys)
                       (zipWith (+) xs (tail ys))
```

To visualize what is going on, recall that

```
foldr1 go [a,b,c,d]
```

performs this transformation:

```
    (:)                             go
   /   \                           /  \
  a    (:)         >==>           a   go
      /   \                          /  \
     b    (:)                       b   go
         /   \                         /  \
        c     d                       c    d
```

So if the lists increase in size going from `a` to `d`, we just write `go` with a signature like:

```
--   (smaller)     (larger)
go :: [Int]     -> [Int]    -> [Int]
go    xs           ys  = ...
```

This means we want to zip `xs` first with `ys` and then with `tail ys`.